# How to get year in Hong kong language (culture info : zh-hk)

Tags: c#, .net

I want to match the string in Hong kong language
I have month and year as below in hongkong language

```
二零一六年六月份  ===>June 2016
二零一五年六月份  ===>June 2015
```

I have use culture info (zh-HK) to get month like

[image]

But how to get year? Please help

Comment: The .NET framework can't. You need a translation engine to do the work for you.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Actually, a very simple translation engine can do the job.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer. I have added working code to help you! :)

Comment: Eastern Asian cultures require more complex extension libraries such as https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18970 So instead of using a code snippet that might not be updated frequent enough, you should check extension libraries like this.

Comment: I just found a bug in my code, please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a dictionary that uses the Chinese characters as the key and the corresponding numbers as the value:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
    {"零", "0"},
    {"一", "1"},
    {"二", "2"},
    {"三", "3"},
    {"四", "4"},
    {"五", "5"},
    {"六", "6"},
    {"七", "7"},
    {"八", "8"},
    {"九", "9"},
    {"十", "1"} // this is needed for the months to work. If you know Chinese you would know what I mean
};
```

Then, you split the input string with the separator "年":

```
string[] twoParts = inputString.Split('年');
```

You loop through each character of the first part. Using the dictionary you created, you can easily get `2016` from `"二零一六"`.

For the second part, check whether `"份"` is present at the end. If it is, substring it off. (sometimes months can be written without "份"). After that, do one more substring to get rid of the "月".

Now you use the dictionary above again to turn something like `"十二"` to `"12"`

Now you have the year and the month, just create a new instance of `DateTime`!

Here's the full code:

```
string inputString = ...;
var dict = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
    {"零", "0"},
    {"一", "1"},
    {"二", "2"},
    {"三", "3"},
    {"四", "4"},
    {"五", "5"},
    {"六", "6"},
    {"七", "7"},
    {"八", "8"},
    {"九", "9"},
    {"十", "1"} // this is needed for the months to work. If you know Chinese you would know what I mean
};

string[] twoParts = inputString.Split ('年');
StringBuilder yearBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
foreach (var character in twoParts[0]) {
    yearBuilder.Append (dict [character.ToString ()]);
}

string month = twoParts [1];
if (month [month.Length - 1] == '份') {
    month = month.Substring (0, month.Length - 1);
}
month = month.Substring (0, month.Length - 1);
StringBuilder monthBuilder = new StringBuilder ();

foreach (var character in month) {
    monthBuilder.Append (dict [character.ToString ()]);
}

var date = new DateTime (Convert.ToInt32 (yearBuilder.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32 (monthBuilder.ToString()), 1);
Console.WriteLine (date);
```

EDIT:

I just realized that this doesn't work if the month is October, in which case it will parse to January. To fix this, you need to use a separate dictionary for the months. Since the SE editor doesn't allow me to enter too many Chinese characters, I will try to tell you want to put in this dictionary in the comments.

When you parse the months, please use the new dictionary. So now the month parsing code will look like this:

```
month = month.Substring (0, month.Length - 1);
string monthNumberString = newDict[month];
```

No need for the for each loop.

Comment: Here are the keys and values for the dictionary: 一 : 1, 二 : 2, 三 : 3, 四 : 4, 五 : 5, 六 : 6, 七 : 7, 八 : 8, 九 : 9, 十 : 10, 十一 : 11, 十二 : 12 You can actually now remove the last KVP of the old dictionary.